# how to wait for returned response from redux actions using UseDispatch Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux and
I am now trying to write a login component.

my redux actions is something like this.

```
export const fetchToken = (params) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        };
    return axios
      .post(`${baseUri}/api/token`, params, config)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGGED_IN,
          payload: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert('Provided username and password is incorrect');
      });
  };
};
```

as you can see I am returning a promise. I try to use it in the component but it's not working.

I am using `useDispatch` hooks from `react-redux`

my code look like this

```
const checkValidate = () => {
        if (email.length < 1 || password.length < 1) {
            alert('Please fill all the details');
            return;
        } else {
            const params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('username', email);
            params.append('password', password);
            params.append('grant_type', 'password');
            dispatch(fetchToken(params)).then((res) => {
                alert('success')
            }).catch((err) => alert('not success'));
        }
        // navigation.navigate('Home');
    };
```

As you can see I am alerting the success. The problem is that if I write the wrong username and password. The response always goes into success response. It will alert success then It will alert the response from the `fetchToken` action which is alert`('Provided username and password is incorrect');` Is there anything wrong with my code.

And also whenever I try to console.log the `then response` it will always return undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```js
.then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGGED_IN,
          payload: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert('Provided username and password is incorrect');
      });
```

you remove the error and the result from the chain. If you want them to be passed to the next .then or .catch, you have to return/rethrow it:

```
.then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGGED_IN,
          payload: res.data,
        });
+       return res
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert('Provided username and password is incorrect');
+       throw err
      });
```